# Star rating in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a star rating system on ASP.NET Core and I currently have this code. However, I am unable to hover over it to change the stars.

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <span class="text-warning">
      <i class="ratingStar fas fa-star"></i>
      <i class="ratingStar far fa-star"></i>
      <i class="ratingStar far fa-star"></i>
      <i class="ratingStar far fa-star"></i>
      <i class="ratingStar far fa-star"></i>
    </span>               
</div>

<script>
    $(".ratingStar").hover(function () {
        $(".ratingStar").addClass("far").removeClass("fas");

        $(this).addClass("fas").removeClass("far");
        $(this).prevAll(".ratingStar").addClass("fas").removeClass("far");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Works for me. Used a stylesheet from fontawesome. https://jsfiddle.net/8mu59xda/

Comment: Able to clarify "unable to hover over it" ?  I can concur that your code should work. Did you add jquery to your page? I noted that you are using jquery in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it by applying CSS. Add following class in your `<style>`. Following is the example:

```
.ratingStar:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```